# ArcGIS Map application with huge data web flex vs desktop

Tags: performance, apache-flex, web-applications, desktop-application, arcgis-server

We are working on a mapping application on ArcGIS Server, the application requires to work with large number of records 100K+ retrieved from the server.

Which is better to build such application as a web using Flex or standalone application? The application uses spatial analyses spatial queries.

Comment: Don't think there's a significant difference, except perhaps you migth want to store some of this data locally (which you can only achieve through a desktop app).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the desktop. Then you can put the data in AIR's sql database, which could save redundant downloads in the future and make it very fast to work with the data.

Answer (score 1):

Flex won't make it ) It will die on 1k while loading all that huge data on your client PC:)
The only way to make it with Flex is to:

1. Use Geodatabases on your server (forget about shapefiles)
2. Create some MapService for that 100k feature dataset (if you want it to be visible in your app)
3. Create geoprocessing tool (Model,Script) for your analysis. And publish it on your AGS as a service.
4. Use AGS API for Flex to call those services.
5. And let your server do the job, and your Flex app will only get the result

*You should not ever load that much data on your client PCs*